# how to know service name of an application?

Tags: linux, service

I installed yammer application in my centos(linux) machine.It is starting at the time of starting the machine.How can i know its service name and how can i delete from startup....?

Answer (score 1):

```
ps ax will display processes currently running by all users while  
ps aux will display processes currently running by the current user.
```

If you combine them with grep hopefully you will find what you are looking for. For example:

```
ps ax | grep yammer
```